# Component model from Vueify is empty

Tags: javascript, json, browserify, vuejs2, vueify

I just now started with Vue.js, and this is the first time I'm trying to use Vueify and Browserify.
I made this simple component to generate a table from a Json, however the div where my component should show up is empty, I don't get any errors and the Vue dev tools extension shows my Json with all the correct data. I'm probably doing something very dumb here, but I can't see it...

My index.html:

```
<div class="content">
        <div id="vuePersonagens"></div>
        <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/components/Personagens/build.js"></script>
</div>
```

Personagens.vue :

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Personagens</h1>
  <table v-for="personagem in personagens" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Raça</th>
      <th>Classe</th>
      <th>Level Efetivo</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>{{ personagem.nome }}</td>
          <td>{{ personagem.raca }}</td>
          <td>{{ personagem.classe }}</td>
          <td>{{ personagem.level }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import * as Vue from 'vue'
  import Component from 'vue-class-component'

  @Component({
      props: {
        personagens: [{ "nome": String, "raca": String, "classe": String, level: Number}]
      }
  })
  export default class Personagens extends Vue {
        personagens: [{ "nome": String, "raca": String, "classe": String, level: Number}]
  }
</script>
```

start.js:

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var Personagens = require('./Personagens.vue')

new Vue({
   el: '#vuePersonagens',
   data: {
     personagens: [{ "nome": "Banjo", "raca": "Lizarkin", "classe": "Bard/Cleric", level: 8}]
   }
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "cleave",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JSON",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://hsaldanha@bitbucket.org/hsaldanha/cleave.git"
  },
  "author": "Heitor Saldanha",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/hsaldanha/cleave#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.32",
    "vue": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-class-component": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vueify": "^9.4.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  }
}
```

[Console showing empty DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3EQY.png)

[Vue devtools shows my Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITiWy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the `Personagens.vue` component in your `start.js` file.

You can either do this globally:

```
Vue.component('personagens', Personagens);
```

Or in the root component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vuePersonagens',
  components: { personagens: Personagens },
  data: {
    ...
  }
})
```

Then, you also need to actually include the component's tag in the template:

```
<div id="vuePersonagens">
  <personagens :personagens="personagens"></personagens>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now for some reason my v-for is not generating rows in my table, any ideia why? I realized the v-for should be in the TR tag, but it still doesn't work....

Comment: You'll also need to pass in the data via the `personagens` property in the tag. I've updated the answer. You have a lot of things named `personagens`, which is confusing. I'd rename your variables to be more distinguishable. Also, these are pretty basic concepts in Vue, I'd read through their documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Thanks so much for you answers, I'll give the docs a more careful read through.